# Semaphore CI fails, but works fine in ssh session

Tags: testing, semaphore-ci

On a SPA project, I'm using SemaphoreCI to run my tests. I've got a simple build process. Only problem is that my project uses a private NPM repository.

For that I need to setup a `.npmrc` file, where a `NPM_TOKEN` is set. That token is saved in Semaphore's environment variables.

Here's the setup I have:

```
echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}" > .npmrc
yarn install
yarn test
```

Pretty simple. However when running the token is not applied and `yarn install` fails with this message:

`error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: pull
Directory: /home/runner/.cache/yarn/v1/.tmp/289ca588f755e265ffc41022e0b6524e
Output:
*** Please tell me who you are.`

The strange thing is. When I use the Launch Session tool and SSH into the server, and that I try these exact commands one by one, everything works fine. I get to install and run the tests with no issues.

What would I need to change to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Can you try to add "yarn cache clean" before running "yarn install"? It seems that the cache is at fault. Feel free to contact us on support with the details, and we will look into it further, if the suggestion doesn't help.


PS. You can also bust the cache, by going to Project Settings > Admin. With this, the "yarn cache clean" command can be left out.

Comment: Thanks @baer it worked. Please write down the answer if you want me to select it.

Comment: It's fine, thanks. The important thing is that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

As @baer suggested, adding `yarn cache clean` did the trick for me. Thanks